# Examples of SizedByteArray in Haskell

Tags: haskell, cryptography

I've been trying to use the [hsblst](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hsblst-0.0.2/docs/Crypto-BLST.html) library and I having problems with [Data.ByteArray.Sized](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/memory-0.18.0/docs/Data-ByteArray-Sized.html). For example, to use `keygen` from `Crypto.BLST` with signature

```hs
keygen :: (ByteArrayAccess ba, 32 <= n, KnownNat n) => SizedByteArray n ba -> SecretKey
```

How do I make a `SizedByteArray n ba` object? In this [link](https://github.com/serokell/hsblst/blob/master/test/Test/BLST.hs) there is an example where

```hs
sk1 = keygen $ AS.unsafeSizedByteArray @32 @ByteString "qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq"
```

where `AS` is an alias for `Data.ByteArray.Sized`. This example is not working for me. When I try to do the same those at_marks do not work.

Then I tried this code

```hs
import Data.ByteArray.Sized qualified as AS
import Data.Text.Encoding
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Data.Text as T
import Data.Proxy (Proxy(..))
import Crypto.BLST

sk ="79cc407e6917b5673a1f6966c23c9e15\
     \d257e5ab46cfe7b9b2f64200f2b2843e"
skp = T.pack sk
skpb = encodeUtf8 skp
```

the name `skpb` is of type `ByteString`. So, according to the definition of `sizedByteArray` (shown below) I should get a `Maybe SizedByteArray` right?

```hs
-- | create a 'SizedByteArray' from the given 'ByteArrayAccess' if the
-- size is the same as the target size.
--
sizedByteArray :: forall n ba . (KnownNat n, ByteArrayAccess ba)
               => ba
               -> Maybe (SizedByteArray n ba)
sizedByteArray ba
    | length ba == n = Just $ SizedByteArray ba
    | otherwise      = Nothing
  where
    n = fromInteger $ natVal (Proxy @n)
```

After trying this I get these errors:

```
ghci> AS.sizedByteArray skpb

<interactive>:7:1: error: [GHC-39999]
    • No instance for ‘GHC.TypeNats.KnownNat n0’
        arising from a use of ‘it’
    • In the first argument of ‘print’, namely ‘it’
      In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

and

```
ghci> keygen $ AS.sizedByteArray skpb

<interactive>:8:1: error: [GHC-64725]
    • Cannot satisfy: 32 <= n0
    • In the first argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘keygen’
      In the expression: keygen $ AS.sizedByteArray skpb
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = keygen $ AS.sizedByteArray skpb
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition:

```
sk1 :: SecretKey
sk1 = keygen $ AS.unsafeSizedByteArray @32 @B.ByteString
               "qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq"
```

will work fine, but you need to enable `DataKinds` to use `32` as a type, `OverloadedStrings` to use a string literal as a `ByteString`, and `TypeApplications` to allow those `@`-marks, which are applications to type-level arguments.  So, the following should compile:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

import Crypto.BLST
import qualified Data.ByteArray.Sized as AS
import qualified Data.ByteString as B

sk1 :: SecretKey
sk1 = keygen $ AS.unsafeSizedByteArray @32 @B.ByteString
               "qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq"
```

More generally, with those extensions enabled, you should be able to construct `SizedByteArray` values using any of the following methods:

```
-- type applications
sba2 = AS.unsafeSizedByteArray @64 @B.ByteString
       "0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123"

-- top-level type signature
sba1 :: AS.SizedByteArray 64 B.ByteString
sba1 = AS.unsafeSizedByteArray
       "0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123"

-- in-line type signature
sba3 = AS.unsafeSizedByteArray
       "0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123"
       :: AS.SizedByteArray 64 B.ByteString
```

Note that these sizes aren't checked at compile time, so the following will compile:

```
sbabadlen = AS.unsafeSizedByteArray @100 @B.ByteString "too short"
```

but throw a runtime exception when it's evaluated.  The "safe" version will also compile:

```
sbabadlen = AS.sizedByteArray @100 @B.ByteString "too short"
```

and will evaluate to `Nothing` instead of `Just` a `SizedByteArray`.

Oh, and I should add: there is no simple way of constructing a `SizedByteArray` without specifying its length explicitly in the source code, so that's why your attempt to have the compiler determine the length based on the actual contents failed with a missing `KnownNat` instance.

Comment: That's great! Thanks a lot! One last question. Everything is compiling fine now, but if I try to do `AS.unsafeSizedByteArray @32 @B.ByteString "qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq"` in `ghci` gives me this error `Illegal type: ‘32’ Perhaps you intended to use DataKinds`. Compiling that instruction, on the other hand, works fine. Why is that?

Comment: You can turn on the `DataKinds` extension in GHCi either using a command line argument when you invoke it:  `ghci -XDataKinds` or at the GHCi prompt using `ghci> :set -XDataKinds`.  After that, it should work.